# Refreshing authentication token

Tags: angular

I want to implement JWT based authentication in Angular2 (my backend is Java Spring where I generate Token and send it back during Login). I kept expiry time as 15 mns (Ideal time) however if the user is active I dont want him to login again.

How to refresh the token if my backend returns new token?

Comment: You would have to do `silent refresh` to refresh token. I use `oidc-client` for this. Here's a good article about it that I have bookmarked: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Silent-Refresh-Refreshing-Access-Tokens-when-using-the-Implicit-Flow

Comment: The best way is to implement an http interceptors, that will check responses. If responses is OK and containing a token in headers, then update the layer which handle the token